# Converting a string to Date in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to parse a string `26/03/2012`, in `dd/mm/yyyy` format to Ruby's Date using `Date.strptime`, as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'date'
puts 'Ruby Version: ' + RUBY_VERSION
date_str = '26/03/2012'

date = Date.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%y")
puts 'Parsed Date: ' + date.to_s
```

The output is:

```
Ruby Version: 1.8.7
Parsed Date: 2020-03-26
```

The year part has become `2020`, instead of `2012`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be `%Y` upper case, rather than `%y`:

```
date = Date.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%Y")
puts 'Parsed Date: ' + date.to_s
# Parsed Date: 2012-03-26
```

[From the docs:](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html)

```
 Date (Year, Month, Day):
    %Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least)
            -0001, 0000, 1995, 2009, 14292, etc.
    %C - year / 100 (round down.  20 in 2009)
    %y - year % 100 (00..99)
```

Since `%y` expects two digits only, it takes the first two `20` and assumes that to be a 2 digit representation of `2020`, since `2020 % 100 = 20`.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation `%y - year % 100` indicates that all 4 digits of the year part should be read, if it reads first 2 digits only then there is no point of doing `year % 100`, which would same as `year` when `year < 100`! But as you say it perhaps reads only first 2 digits!

Comment: Yeah I saw `(00..99)` in the docs, this part is contradicting the `%y - year % 100` part! Is not it? :)

Comment: I think its doing `%y - year / 100`, tried with **4042** as the year and it printed **2040** as the year. Had it been doing `%y - year % 100` I would got what I wanted.

Comment: @Curious Not contradictory, just confusing.  _You_ are expected to be supplying the result of `year % 100`, so if you give it `20` as the result of `year % 100`, it extrapolates the current century.  The `%y - ` part _isnt't subtraction_, it's just how they printed it in the docs. No calculation takes place.

Comment: The result of `2040` from `4042` is exactly expected because again, `2040 % 100 = 40`. It expects 2 digits and uses the first 2 it finds. The others are discarded because it doesn't realize you are trying to give it the year `4042`, it just sees a string `"4042"`

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `strptime` function to
`date = Date.striptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%Y")`

it will output correctly.