# Ruby doesn't want to format string to date

Tags: ruby

I need to format a string to date:

```
date = DateTime.parse("05/15/2017")
formatted_date = date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
puts formatted_date
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
`parse': invalid date (ArgumentError)
```

And if I try to parse `15/05/2017` then it works.

How to parse `05/15/2017` into `%m/%d/%Y` format?

Comment: Specify format when parsing, obviously. Look up `strptime`.

Comment: Your code puzzles me. First you parse a date string, and then you turn it into a string again? What's the point? What is it that you _actually_ want to do, parse or format?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's not as strange as you might think. plenty of applications have users input a date and then later display the date in a similar or the same format. i'm sure den plans to do stuff with the date other than parsing it and displaying it, but questions on stackoverflow are supposed to cut out the irrelevant code and focus on the problem.

Comment: @eiko: "cut out the irrelevant code and focus on the problem" - this one failed to do that, though. :) Or, rather, question title doesn't reflect actual content and problem.

Comment: @eiko: it's infinitely easier to format dates in whatever way than to parse dates (correctly) in whatever format (not knowing the format). Of course, if there's only one mandated input format, then it's easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to Date in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198749/converting-a-string-to-date-in-ruby)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko more likely a duplicate of [ruby datetime parsing from mm-dd-yyyy format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643444/ruby-datetime-parsing-from-mm-dd-yyyy-format)

Comment: `Ruby doesn't want` - funny title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the first line that raises the error, because `Date.parse` doesn't know how to handle the string `"05/15/2016"`. Use [`Date.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) instead and tell Ruby how to read the string:

```
DateTime.strptime('05/15/2017', '%m/%d/%Y')
#=> #<DateTime: 2017-05-15T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457889j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Thanks Mann :) Perfect